# SSRS Count total rows by month (and year)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm learning SSRS and want to count number of DB rows by the date column in a table

It must look like this e.g. for 2018

```
---------------------------------------------
|   Month     |  Jan  |  Feb  | etc.....
---------------------------------------------
|Total Rows   |   10  |   15  | ............
---------------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure how to get this. I can only output all the row dates in a big list.
I know I need to group but not sure how.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Jan and Feb examples would you just have 10 records in Jan and 15 in Feb?

If so then you use a matrix control and add a column group that groups on month. Then drop the field that contains the values you want to count in the data cell.

If the data is numeric SSRS will add a sum by default '=SUM(Fields!myField.Value)` but you can change this to a count.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    [Month] = 'Total Rows',
    [Jan]   = SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DateColumn) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [Feb]   = SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DateColumn) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    ...
    [Dec]   = SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DateColumn) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    DateColumn >= '2018-01-01'
    AND DateColumn < '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into this.